# Unwanted horizontal scroll bar in all the pages in Firefox browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

There is a horizontal scroll bar in the bottom of this site in all the pages in Firefox browser.
There is no use of the horizontal scroll bar in the pages.

**Configurations:**
OS: Windows 10 Pro
Mozilla Firefox: 54.0 (32-bit)
Zoom : 100%
Screen resolution: 1600 x 900

Screenshot for reference:

[image: horizontal Scroll bar]

Comment: I can confirm this on my system. OS Win 7, Firefox 55.0.2. Zooming or increasing the window width does not change this.

Comment: @Paweł Looks like the horizontal scroll bar issue has been fixed in the `rev 2017.8.24.26841`